# Undefined variable error while calling a field in another method

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to set a value for a field in a method and get the value in another method in larvel controller as the following the code.

```
class LoginController extends Controller {

    public $authUser;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->authUser = null;
    }


    public function methodA()
    {
         // some code to get the $response
         $this->authUser = $response;
    }


    public function methodB()
    {
         var_dump($this->authUser);
    }
}
```

But I got the following error:

**(1/1) ErrorException
Undefined variable: authUser**

why it is happen. I could not figure what's happen on my site.

Comment: How you make a call to this methods?

Comment: Btw, the `__construct ` method is useless in your code so you don't need that.

Comment: What @SR_ says, how do you call these methods? And check your `laravel.log`, is the error actually occurring in the controller or somewhere else?